# What are the implications of exponential growth of information?

Tags: physics, information-theory, philosophy

The fact that linear growth of information (1,2,3.. bits) results in an exponential growth of the accumulated information (2,4,8.. possible values) seems to be very fundamental.

What are the implications of this fact on Mathematics and physics? Can you name same laws and theorems or other consequences?

Comment: [Shannon Entropy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Shannon_entropy).

Comment: Why should it be fundamental? It is just the way bits are defined that make the growth exponential. And btw, that is not how information is defined.